# postgres: Trying to join 4 tables based on a conditional

Tags: postgresql, join, case

I have 4 tables.  table1 has one column called reportable_type and another column called reportable_id.  reportable type has two values, table2 or table3.  table2 and table3 both have a column for table4_id.  I am trying to write a query that gets me table1.id and table4.description in one result.  It feels like a case statement on postgres would get me there but I am getting lost, also two case statements probably is breaking this:

```
select t1.id, t4.description 
from table1 as t1
case 
  when t1.reportable_type = ’table2’
    then left join table2 as t2 on t1.reportable_id = t2.id
    else left join table3 as t3 on t1.reportable_id = t3.id
end
left join table4 as t4 on 
case 
  when t1.reportable_type = ’table2’
    then t2.table4_id =t4.id
    else t3.table4_id =t4.id
end
group by t4.description;
```

EDIT:
Wanting to add some data around this so it is clearer. 
Lets use the following data:

```
table 1
IDs - 1, 2
reportable_type - table 2, table 3
reportable_id - 1, 1 

table 2:
id - 1
t4_id - 1

table 3:
id - 1
t4_id - 2

table 4:
id - 1 ,2
description - first, second
```

So the resulting table from the query should be:

```
id - 1,2
description - first, second
```

Comment: You cannot just bend syntax rules to your liking. Specifically, `case` has no place in the `from` clause, as I'm sure you know. Put it where it _does_ have place -- in the `select` list.

Comment: Unless postgresql is vastly different, you can't use a case this way on a join.  you could make a "AND statement on each checking for table2 or not table2; but this use of case just seems odd.

Comment: Agree, the issue I am have here is I am not sure how to get this relation to work.  Completely agree the above syntax does not work but figured it would give a clearer idea of what I am trying to do.

Comment: @xQbert I am not sure how to use an and statement to make a conditional on which table to join.  Could you expand a bit on that?

Comment: You can left join all the required tables and then conditionally show data from which table you require in the select, but you can't conditionally join, unless you move into more procedural SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have to left join on t2 and t3 knowing only 1 will resolve since t1.reportable_Type can't be <> 'table2' and = table2. Then we can `coalesce` the value for the relationship to t4 from either ID in T3, t2.

This does mean that both left joins have to attempt to be resolved so it may not be as efficient as trying to figure out how to execute only one of the left joins. But the results should be accurate.  Once you get this working, if performance is a problem, we'd need to look at execution plans/indexes to see if there's another way to optimize it.

```
SELECT t1.id, t4.description 
FROM table1 as t1
LEFT join table2 as t2 
  on t1.reportable_id = t2.id
 and t1.reportable_type = 'table2'
LEFT join table3 as t3 
  on t1.reportable_id = t3.id
 and coalesce(t1.reportable_type,'isNull') <> 'table2'
LEFT join table4 as t4
  on t4.id = coalesce(t2.table4_id, t3.table4_ID)
--GROUP BY t4.description;
```

Not sure why you have a group by w/o aggregation. so I commented it out; maybe you mean `ORDER BY`; I generally find it wise to include order by on nearly all queries; especially those that can make use of indexes.

I also added   `and coalesce(t1.reportable_type,'isNull') <> 'table2'` to use coalesce to handle the situation if t1.reportable_type is null.  I assume you'd still want those records as null is not equal to 'table2' but you may not want those records at all; so we'd need more info on that specific case.

The <> join condition on the t3 may be a bit of a performance hog as well since I don't believe an index can be used.  but I'm not sure how to work around it yet perhaps an in or exists and a subquery would work... but I'll let you play from here.

Comment: Wow that is exactly what I was looking for.  Excited to research a couple of things I never heard of in coalesce and <> .  Thanks alot.

Comment: `<>` is just `!=` both are not equal. I prefer `<>` vs `!=`.  and coalesce is simply returning the first non null value in a series of values so we could `coalesce(varA, varB, varC, 'Error')` if we wanted and if a,b,c were all null error would be returned (I believe coalese does require all the datatypes to be the same however).  In this case since we know one of the two will always have a value coalesce should work.  also bear in mind the `<>` on a join means no index can be used for that criteria; so performance could be bad if table size grows.

Comment: on the coalesce wouldn't it cause an issue since the id values are just just increasing integers, both t2 and t3 could have a similar id?  Or does the on/and clause pick the correct table to associate for a given row?

Comment: Lets look at the pseudo logic you have in your example:  Doesn't the same issue apply there?  if table4_ID in t2 and t3 overlap, then we need an additional element on which to base T4's join.  and since reportable_type isn't in t4... I don't see what we could limit on.  I'd need more info and some sample data; showing this case w/ expected results.  Now keep in mind in the t2, t3 left joins ONLY one of those has values, the other will ALWAYS be null; so it can only join on 1 table in the first place.

Comment: On a different note if t1.reportable_type can be null then the <> will fail so we may need to `coalesce(t1.reportable_type,'isNull')` to handle Null values correctly. otherwise we don't handle all the t1.reportable_type possibilities.  (meaning some records may not show up since NULL  can't be evaluated on  <> it comes back null which isn't true so any such data wouldn't be returned in the join)  this is one of the dangers and Null and <> or not in.  It's generally better to use the = vs `<>` when you can when you can; to avoid the Null case and help w/ indexes

Comment: added some data in the edit.  Let me know if that is helpful

Comment: I took the data and created a rextester script: http://rextester.com/UQJ28028  I'm not sure this tests/proves anything yet; other than it returned expected results...  We need more edge case data to prove out if it will work when  table2 or 3 share an table4 ID (assuming it's a possibility); or if you want to see how "Null's in a reportable type are handled.

Comment: Seems to work well.  For some reason on my data set it seems to drop fields.  Let me look into my case more and then try to add to the rextester and will repost.

Comment: Looks like it works, the issue I was having was with a data inconsistency that I didn't realize, but was able to edit the query to fix it!